# Can I frame basement walls over slab cracks?

Tags: concrete, basement, framing, basement-refinishing

[image]

I recently bought a home with an unfinished basement and would like to start finishing it to add onto the livable space our of house.

Do I need to repair cracks in my slab before I start framing walls? Can I frame walls directly over these cracks and put down a subfloor? If I nail into the slab do I risk creating more cracks and an unstable wall?

FWIW, in my year and a half of being at the house, I have not seen any water rise up from the cracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the floor was poured after the foundation walls. The cracks look like the normal expansions cracks that most all slabs get.

Assuming the walls you want to build are partition rather than load bearing and you are not removing any supporting elements from the basement you will have no problem.

It would be best practice to fill the cracks and the gap around the perimeter with some caulking and add a sealer to the floor to fend off moisture. ( Again assuming you will be covering the floor.)

Drilling for screws or power-nailing the bottom plate of the walls should not degrade the floor or cause more cracks.  ( of course if you are to screw or nail directly over a crack it can further chip out. This is still minor.)

Unless you have a party of hammer wielding friends there banging on the floor, you should be fine building your walls.

Good Luck

Comment: Agree, I would use an elastomeric filler before putting up the walls. I hope the stud is there just for the pic, otherwise you have no bottom plate (which should be PT or have a gasket).

Comment: I'd especially lean toward sealing first if you're in an area with known radon issues. Easier to do now than later.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response, RMDman, and for the comments everyone! Yes, none of these walls would be load bearing - they are all partition walls. Huesmann, that stud in the picture is just a stand-in and has not been mounted to anything. I will look into some elastometric sealant to fill the cracks. As for the framing, I was planing on going with steal but was going to use a PT as the base with a regular piece of wood on top, and then the steel base track as the top layer. The regular piece is to mount trim at the base (as oppose to mounting into the steal). Is that a good approach?